# How to control order of testNG package test execution without Priority or Dependency?

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng, grid

I have a package containing the tests I want to run. There are no priority or dependency setings at the testcase or suite level.

```
<suite thread-count="1" name="reg 1">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="my.org.project.listeners.TestcaseOrdering" />
    </listeners>
    <test name="Regression" preserve-order="true">
        <packages>
            <package name="my.org.testsuites" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

The listener `TestcaseOrdering` implements `IMethodInterceptor`. In my `intercept()` implementation I re-order the tests based on my criteria (run the tests that have run the least # of times first, based on an external DB tracking test results). I store the list to return in an `ArrayList<IMethodInstance>`, which guarantees that the order is preserved.

When TestNG executes the tests it does not respect the order of the list I return. It runs the test cases in a fixed order (meaning, the same each time I run). The order does not have a recognizable sequence; the methods are pulled from various class files and aren't in alpha or numeric order.

I'm stumped as to how to get TestNG to respect my order.  Based on the [documentation](https://jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/IMethodInterceptor.html), this is the place I should be doing this re-ordering.

I discovered the issue when using Selenium Grid, but removing Grid (setting the thread count to 1) doesn't change the behavior.